# Finding database related issue

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database

I've been writing code to transfer credits from one user to another, I've picked MongoDB as database. But I'm told that I have database related issues in the transferCredits function. I've been searching but couldn't find any issue.

```
function transferCredits(from, to, amt) {
  var fromAccount = db.game_accounts.findOne({"name": from},{"credits": 1});
  var toAccount = db.game_accounts.findOne({"name": to},{"credits": 1});
  if (fromAccount.credits < amt) {
    throw new BalanceError("not enough balance to transfer credits");
  }
  db.game_accounts.update({name: from}, {$set: {credits: fromAccount.credits - amt}});
  db.game_accounts.update({name: to}, {$set: {credits: toAccount.credits + amt}});
}

db.game_accounts.insert({name: "John", credits: 1000});
db.game_accounts.insert({name: "Jane", credits: 1000});

// John transfers credits to Jane
transferCredits("John", "Jane", 100);
```

Comment: Whoever told you that could have been more specific and simply said "transactions" are generally required to ensure consistency between multiple write operations. Their specific language though is typical of the sort of  prejudiced nonsense spouted by the ill informed as they are inferring "the database" ( MongoDB ) cannot handle such a process through lack of support for transactions. Your "implementation" has this failing, but it is very possible with different modelling to have such a "debit/credit" balanced transaction with MongoDB. You just do it differently.

Answer (score 3):

You are not telling us what the problem is, so we can only speculate...

What I see is that this part could be wrong:

```
db.game_accounts.update({name: from}, {$set: {credits: fromAccount.credits - amt}});
db.game_accounts.update({name: to}, {$set: {credits: toAccount.credits + amt}});
```

This is because there might be another transaction happening between the `findOne()` and the `update()`. You're better using `$inc` which will perform the same operation but without opening yourself to race conditions.

```
db.game_accounts.update({name: from}, {$inc: {credits: amt*-1}},function(err,res){
    if (err) throw err;
    db.game_accounts.update({name: to}, {$inc: {credits: amt}}, function(err,res){
        if (err) throw err;
        db.game_accounts.update({name: from}, {$inc: {credits: amt}});
    });
});
```

Note that to substract I simply multiply by -1 to turn the number negative.

Besides that, if the user tries to give -10 credits to another user, he will be able to STEAL 10 credits instead... Multiple other checks need to be done like that to ensure a valid transaction.

On a side note, MongoDB is not really meant for this kind of transaction, you might prefer using another kind of DB which can make sure that the data is up to date and all operations are tracked and done.

Comment: What is to speculate? If you actually understood this very common financial systems pattern it basically means you need a "pair" of entries that "debit" and "credit" the same amount, both out of one account and into another. As commented, the "database related issue" means "transactions", or "lack thereof" in MongoDB. So if you have "two writes' ( as both the OP's question and your response have ) then what happens when one of those fails? If you are going to submit an answer, you **must** understand the question first.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a ,somwhat naive, way to handle the transaction accordingly. But I keep saying that it is pure speculation that the question was about this exact matter... As there are many other possible problems in the given code snippet.

Comment: From my read of this, I don't think you understand it very well. The "MongoDB way" to implement this would involve just "one write operation".

Comment: Maybe, I am no expert. Just trying to help with what I know, since you don't want to give out a clean answer, someone has to try at least... No?